# Store Date Time with Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, datetime, oracle11g, oracle-apex

There is a hidden field as `last_updated_date` in my Oracle Apex application form. I have set `SYSDATE` as default value of that field. After adding data, I'v checked database table and data in `last_updated_date` column is show as `15-JUN-12 00:00:00`. Time is not saved.

How could I save both date and time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the hidden item's properties set:

- Source Format Mask to `DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS`
- Default Value to `TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS')`
- Default Value Type to `PL/SQL Expression`

Answer (score 0):

In 4.2.6 that does not work. It will only work with format dd-mon-yyyy or your standard database format
(NLS_FORMAT). The other thing you could do is try to set default formats at application level for your app. That might work. It seems that for hidden fields the formatting does not get honoured for default values and hence you run into errors like "ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string"

Answer (score 0):

Above answers didn't work. In Apex 4.2 (or probably higher) Try this:

Display as: Text Field (didn't try hidden yet)
source used: "Always, replacing any existing value in session state"
source type: "Database Column"
Source value or expression: 'COLUMN_NAME' case sensitive
Post Calculation Computation: to_char(sysdate,'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi')
format mask: "mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi"(no quotes)
Dafault value: sysdate
Default Value Type: PL/SQL Expression

In "Processes" - After Submit
Type: PL/SQL Anonymous Block
On Submit - After Computations and Validations
Declare

begin
  update table_name
   set column_name = sysdate
   where trunc(sysdate) = column_name;

commit;

end;